# how to pass login credentials between pages in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am creating a banking application using oracle apex. once the user have logged in using his customer id in page 2, his account details table should be displayed in the next page. I've tried with 
select acc_no, bal from acc_details where cust_id= :P2_USERNAME

but I'm getting 'NO DATA FOUND'.

is this the correct way to do this? I've tried to use branches too. That was also not working.

Comment: Is page 2 your login page? You're not using the default P101? Is page 2 built on the same principles you'd find in the default login page? I hope it's using an authentication scheme?

Answer (score 0):

On your first page, under the "Behavior"(APEX 5)/"Action When Button Clicked"(APEX 4) attribute of your log in button set "Action" to "Redirect to page in this Application". Then set the Target page number. Under that, you'll see the 'Set Items' part. Fill up that part by setting the "Name"(APEX 5) / "Set these Items"(APEX 4) with :P2_USERNAME and then "Value"(APEX 5)/ "With these Values"(APEX 4) with :P1_USERNAME. Get rid of the "branches" that you've created before or disable them at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

if your user login name and userid is same (like email address)
you may use

```
apex_authentication.get_login_username_cookie
```

for getting username/user id at each page

or you can create an application item in shared component and assign user id to this item as

```
:MY_APP_ITEM := 'Hello';
```

after login and call it from all pages

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using :APP_USER? If that didn't work you could try creating an Application item as a value container for your cust_id. Just go to Shared Components >> Application Items then create an item. This way you could reuse the value on the application item until your session expire or you clear its value.

Say you've created an Application Item named "G_CUST_ID", you want to store your cust_id's value to G_CUST_ID. Create a PL/SQL process on your log in page and write the code below:

apex_util.set_session_state('G_CUST_ID', :P2_USERNAME);

The value set on G_CUST_ID will reset automatically on session expire. Don't forget to reset the value manually on Log Out.

apex_util.set_session_state('G_CUST_ID', NULL);